# create registration form and login form

Tags: apex, visualforce

Hi I have requirement to create a simple registration form and login form. Registrtion form has filed name like name, phone, username and password, and login form has username and password as field.

When user click on login button if user exist it should display userdetails like name, phone, etc on another page. So I have created login page and I am able to display user details, but not in other page but in the same page. So I need a help to display user details in another visualforce page. Thanks for the help in adavance. Below is my code

```java
public class LoginForm {
    String userName;
    String password;
    List<Registration_Form__c>  regs;

    public void setuserName(String u){
        userName = u;
    }
    public String getuserName(){
        return userName;
    }
    public void setpassword(String u){
        password = u;
    }
    public String getpassword(){
        return password;
    }
    public List<Registration_Form__c> getregs(){
        return regs;
    }
        
    public PageReference loginForm() {
        regs = [Select Name,LastName__c,Email__c,Phone__c,userName__c From Registration_Form__c Where Username__c=:userName  AND Password__c=:password];       
        return null;
    }
    
    public PageReference registerUser() {
        PageReference newPage = new PageReference('https://c.ap16.visual.force.com/apex/RegistrationForm?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1');
        newPage.setRedirect(true);
        return newPage;
    }
    public PageReference Cancel() {
        PageReference newPage = new PageReference(System.currentPageReference().getURL());
        newPage.setRedirect(true);
        return newPage;
    }
}
```

```html
<apex:page controller="LoginForm" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="true">
    <apex:Pagemessages id="msg"/>   
    <center>
        <apex:form style="border-style:hidden;border-width:Medium;background-size:25% 20%">
            <font size="25px" color="Green" text_align="Centre"> <b> Login Form  </b> </font>
            <br> <br>   
            <font size ="3px"><b> UserName </b></font>
            <apex:inputText required="true" id="username" value="{!username}"/></br></br>
            
            <br>    
            <font size ="3px"><b> Password </b></font>
            <apex:inputSecret id="password" value="{!password}"/></br>
            <br></br>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!loginForm}" value="login" id="login"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel" id="cancel"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!registerUser}" value="Register" id="register"  immediate="true"/>
            <apex:pageBlock >
        
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!regs}" var="a">
                    <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!a.LastName__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!a.Email__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!a.Phone__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!a.UserName__c}"/>
               </apex:pageBlockTable>
           </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </center>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: More details are required. What do you mean by "another page"? truly another page, or something like a modal dialogue? This also sounds incredibly insecure. I's suggest going to trailhead to learn some of the basics of visualforce pages (and navigation between pages).